# Using Promise.reject() for Error-Handling in http.post

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, post

I wrote a login method which sends a http post to an authorization service. If the credentials are wrong, the service returns a 403.

My idea is to return a Promise.reject() and let the caller catch the rejection to show an alert. My problem is, the calling method does not handle the error correctly.

Is there anything I am doing wrong with my error procedure?

```
public async login(username: string, password: string): Promise<void> {
  let authToken = null;
  const obj = this;
  const url = this.backendService.getAuthServiceURL(username, password);
  this.http.post<any>(url, { }, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders(),
    observe: 'response',
  }).subscribe(
      (result) => {
        authToken = result.headers.get('Authorization');
        localStorage.setItem(authTokenIdentifier, authToken);
        obj.username = username;
        localStorage.setItem(usernameIdentifier, username);
      },
      (error) => {
        if (error.status === 403) {
          localStorage.removeItem(authTokenIdentifier);
          return Promise.reject(error.message);
        } else {
          return Promise.reject(error.message);
        }
      },
      () => {
      },
  );
  }
```

```
async login(): Promise<void> {
  this.authService.login(this.username, this.password)
      .then( () => console.log("SUCCESS!"))
      .catch(() => console.log("ERROR!"));
}
```

I already tried wrapping the authService.login call in Try/Catch, calling it with await

```
await this.authService.login(this.username, this.password)
```

and not running the code async at all.

Thank you for any advice in advance.

Edit:
If I understand you guys correctly, returning the Error wrapped in a Promise is unnecessary and/or can cause problems. I have to admit I didn't really understand that subscribe will create an Observable.

```
  (error) => {
        if (error.status === 403) {
          localStorage.removeItem(authTokenIdentifier);
          throwError(error.message);
        } else {
          throwError(error.message);
        }
      },
```

I tried throwing the error directly with the same result.

Comment: Is there a reason you're wrapping the observable in a promise?

Comment: I would highly suggest not wrapping a Promise in an Observable, it will lead to unexpected outcomes like you are seeing. You can convert an observable to a promise if you wish by `.toPromise()` on an rxjs observable.

Comment: "My idea is to return a Promise.reject()" - but the observer is the end of the chain. The return value, if any, won't be consumed by anyone.

Comment: Sorry for digging it up again, I hadn't much time to work on it. Can anyone of you guys check out my update please? Thank you